# How to have an on off switch, display one on and one off at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an on-off switch and would like for one to display as off (grey color) and one to display as on (blue color), with on being the default. In this specific case, I want the first row to have blue "on" elements, with the second and third-row displaying the toggle switch as off or grey.

I've tried adding additional elements in the css but nothing has worked so far.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 38px;
  height: 22px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #98B3DD;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  left: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgb(221, 223, 235);
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush"></ul>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-11">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Device 1</td>
            <td><i class="far fa-edit fa-2x text-#98B3DD" style="font-size: 25px;height: 22px;margin-left: 2px;margin-right: 2px;"></i></td>
            <td><i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x text-#98B3DD" style="font-size: 25px;"></i></td>
            <td><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" /><span class="slider round"></span></label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Device 2</td>
            <td><i class="far fa-edit fa-2x text-gray-300" style="font-size: 25px;height: 22px;margin-left: 2px;margin-right: 2px;"></i></td>
            <td><i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x text-gray-300" style="font-size: 25px;"></i></td>
            <td><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" /><span class="slider round"></span></label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Device 3</td>
            <td><i class="far fa-edit fa-2x text-gray-300" style="font-size: 25px;height: 22px;margin-left: 2px;margin-right: 2px;"></i></td>
            <td><i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x text-gray-300" style="font-size: 25px;"></i></td>
            <td><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" /><span class="slider round"></span></label></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-11">
    <div><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#addnewdevice">Add New Device</button>
      <div class="collapse" id="addnewdevice">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found a solution, the comments in the code explain the changes I have made.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 38px;
  height: 22px;
}

.switch input {
  display:none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #98B3DD;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  left: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgb(221, 223, 235);
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}



/* ADDED THIS BELOW */ 

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(16px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(16px);
  transform: translateX(16px);
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- In the input tag I added the word *checked* for Device 1  and left it out for Device 2 and Device 3 -->

<ul class="list-group list-group-flush"></ul>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-11">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr></tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Device 1</td>
                                <td><i class="far fa-edit fa-2x text-#98B3DD" style="font-size: 25px;height: 22px;margin-left: 2px;margin-right: 2px;"></i></td>
                                <td><i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x text-#98B3DD" style="font-size: 25px;"></i></td>
                                <td><label class="switch"><input checked type="checkbox" /><span class="slider round"></span></label></td>
                            </tr>

                          <tr>
                                <td>Device 2</td>
                                <td><i class="far fa-edit fa-2x text-#98B3DD" style="font-size: 25px;height: 22px;margin-left: 2px;margin-right: 2px;"></i></td>
                                <td><i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x text-#98B3DD" style="font-size: 25px;"></i></td>
                                <td><label class="switch"><input  type="checkbox" /><span class="slider round"></span></label></td>
                            </tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td>Device 3</td>
                                <td><i class="far fa-edit fa-2x text-#98B3DD" style="font-size: 25px;height: 22px;margin-left: 2px;margin-right: 2px;"></i></td>
                                <td><i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x text-#98B3DD" style="font-size: 25px;"></i></td>
                                <td><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" /><span class="slider round"></span></label></td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-11">
                <div><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#addnewdevice">Add New Device</button>
                    <div class="collapse" id="addnewdevice">
```

Comment: @EmmaChisholm If this worked for you, be sure to click the checkmark next to the answer's score to indicate to others that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have added two css classes (.switch-on and .switch-off) to display switch in on and off state. Is this something like what you want ?

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 38px;
  height: 22px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  bottom: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.slider-on {
  background-color: #98b3dd;
}

.slider-off {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.slider-on::before {
  left: 3px;
}

.slider-off::before {
  right: 3px;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgb(221, 223, 235);
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-11">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Device 1</td>
            <td>
              <i class="far fa-edit fa-2x text-#98B3DD" style="font-size: 25px;height: 22px;margin-left: 2px;margin-right: 2px;"></i>
            </td>
            <td>
              <i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x text-#98B3DD" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>
            </td>
            <td>
              <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox"/><span
                      class="slider slider-on round"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Device 2</td>
            <td>
              <i class="far fa-edit fa-2x text-gray-300" style="font-size: 25px;height: 22px;margin-left: 2px;margin-right: 2px;"></i>
            </td>
            <td>
              <i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x text-gray-300" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>
            </td>
            <td>
              <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox"/><span
                      class="slider slider-off round"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Device 3</td>
            <td>
              <i class="far fa-edit fa-2x text-gray-300" style="font-size: 25px;height: 22px;margin-left: 2px;margin-right: 2px;"></i>
            </td>
            <td>
              <i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x text-gray-300" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>
            </td>
            <td>
              <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox"/><span
                      class="slider slider-off round"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```